# CSS Print Mode - Div at bottom of final page

Tags: html, css, pdf, printing, itext

I have a HTML page with a CSS print layout where I want one of the divs, to always appear at the bottom of the final printed page without overlapping any of the other pages.

I've tried various things, including position:fixed;bottom:0; but when converted to a PDF with iText, that div was in the same position on every page.

Thanks.

Comment: please specify a browser. IE behaves differently then the normal browsers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried Sticky footer? Always worked for me (IE / FF / Webkit)

http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/

Comment: I already go to that page, then use firebug to add more paragraph (to try print more than 1 page). then print that page. it work on screen only (not on print mode). div still on the bottom of last paragraph. Not at bottom last page

Answer (score 1):

How about: a max-height and min-height the same for the printing page and the div positioned absoluted at bottom 0?